# Resequence and renumber a list of commands

Tags: awk

I'm trying to resequence and renumber the following block of commands, so that each command follows numbering that follows a structure such as this:

```
0.1
0.2
..
0.9
1.0
1.1
..
```

So far I'm able to pull the lines with numbers by using the following command, but am unsure what the best way to perform the resequence + renumbering would be. Can I get some assistance around this?

```
awk '$2 ~ /\y[0-9]+\y/' eem.txt
```

OUTPUT TO BE FILTERED

```
 event manager applet monitorHealth authorization bypass
    event manager applet monitorHealth
    event syslog pattern xx maxrun 50 ratelimit 50
    action 0.1 cli command xx
    action 0.2 cli command xx
    action 0.4 cli command xx
    action 0.4 cli command xx
    action 0.4 cli command "undebug all”
    action 0.3 cli command xx
    action 0.4 cli command xx
    action 0.5 cli command xx
    action 0.6 cli command xx
    action 0.7 cli command xx
    action 0.8 cli command xx
    action 0.9 cli command xx
    action 1.1 cli command xx
    action 1.2 cli command xx
    action 1.3 cli command xx
    action 1.4 cli command xx
    action 1.5 cli command xx
    action 1.6 cli command xx
    action 1.7 cli command xx
    action 1.8 cli command xx
    action 1.9 cli command xx
    action 2.1 cli command xx
    action 2.2 cli command xx
    action 2.3 cli command xx
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `sort` command for this.

Comment: please post the input

Comment: Barmar - great idea. Sort does the trick, however the numbers still need to be resequenced. If you check the input file, you will see that there are duplicate numbers which need to follow the above numbering convention. Not sure how to go about this.

hek2mgl - input file is specified above under "OUTPUT TO BE FILTERED"

Comment: What do you mean by 'resequenced' if not sorted?

Comment: @Shawn there are some statements which have numbering as follows: 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4 etc. This needs to be corrected to 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 etc.

Comment: You mean you want the entire thing renumbered, ignoring what the current numbers are?

Comment: @Shawn yes that is correct. I will modify the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To renumber the lines, just have a counter for the new number, and for each matching line, replace that second column's current value with it and increment by 0.1.

```
$ awk -v counter=0.1 '$2 ~ /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]$/ { $1 = "    " $1; # Keep the leading spaces
                                               $2 = sprintf("%.1f", counter);
                                               counter += 0.1 } 1' eem.txt
event manager applet monitorHealth authorization bypass
    event manager applet monitorHealth
    event syslog pattern xx maxrun 50 ratelimit 50
    action 0.1 cli command xx
    action 0.2 cli command xx
    action 0.3 cli command xx
    action 0.4 cli command xx
    action 0.5 cli command "undebug all”
    action 0.6 cli command xx
    action 0.7 cli command xx
    action 0.8 cli command xx
    action 0.9 cli command xx
    action 1.0 cli command xx
    action 1.1 cli command xx
    action 1.2 cli command xx
    action 1.3 cli command xx
    action 1.4 cli command xx
    action 1.5 cli command xx
    action 1.6 cli command xx
    action 1.7 cli command xx
    action 1.8 cli command xx
    action 1.9 cli command xx
    action 2.0 cli command xx
    action 2.1 cli command xx
    action 2.2 cli command xx
    action 2.3 cli command xx
    action 2.4 cli command xx
```

Comment: Great, this is just what I was looking for. Few questions - is %1.1f equivalent to %.1f in printf? And can you please explain the significance of "1" in the last part of the awk one-liner } 1' eem.txt ? Thanks.

Comment: @user `1` at the end of an awk script is a common idiom. It's short for `1 { print }` and prints the current line. A `(s)printf` format of `%.1f` just formats the number with 1 digit after the decimal, in this case so that 1 is rendered as 1.0.